# Extracted CSV as Array for Custom Query Loop

Tags: database, query, csv

How can one extract via PHP the Infos in the CSV/ Excel file.

I have a excel file with over 100 entrys and many rows and i would to like place the file in CSV format on the server and then extract the entrys as array so that one cann a custom query without saving it to the MYSQL Database und when one change the placed the CSV file or uptadet is with new entrys then it uptaded the displayed loop based on the uptaded file.

Comment: How does this relate to WordPress?

Comment: Oh sry, i have a wordpress site and ask how do it in with wp / php. That one can place a csv file on the server and via php one can create a loop on the extraxcted data without save it to wp database.

Comment: You'd probably have more luck on Stack Overflow